# MVC5/EF6 RoleManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

In my `Index.cshtml` I am checking for the `Role` of a `User`.

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin") || Roles.IsUserInRole("Standard"))
{
}
```

When I load the `Index.cshtml` in my browser, I receive this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
```

I have read multiple solutions that don't work for me:

- Remove `RoleManager` in `web.config`.
- Use `[InitializeSimpleMembership]` (won't work, because of MVC5 using Identity)
- Add a `provider` to `system.web.roleManager` in `web.config`.

All of those things haven't worked out for me. I really want to use authentication/authorization in MVC5/EF6. I'd like instructions for MVC5/EF6/Identity, as most people answer for MemberShip or something else.

Comment: What happens if you use `User.IsInRole("...")`

Comment: Hey, that works just great! Could you elaborate on this solution, please?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work when logged in. I receive the same error again.

Comment: Hm, try to undo the changes you did beforehand. Are you using the boilerplate authentication setup, that comes out of the box?

Comment: Like the points from OP? I have reverted them already. So my authentication code is clean, out of the box. Only thing changed is that I enabled roleManager in web.config

Comment: @Tobias Have you got any idea about this?

Comment: I would suggest reverting your web.config back to the state it was before. If you have `<roleManager enabled="true" />` in your web.config, then try deleting that line. Otherwise, try creating a new project, or find examples online, and compare the configuration of these with your own.

Comment: That solved everything, thank you so much, Tobias!

Comment: You are welcome. :) I have added the answer to your initial question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Roles` class which you are using, is a leftover from the old Membership days, an auth framework, which has now been replaced by ASP.NET Identity. To perform role checks, you have to do it via the `User` property, an IPrincipal that's populated by the OWIN authentication middleware. Your code will end up looking like:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("Standard"))
{
    ....
}
```